# How to access one VM from another VM?

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I have two VMs running on my machine, using VmWare Player (Linux). The network configuration used is **NAT** for each VM. [Here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_nat.html) is the link to vmware player's network configuration i have used.

> VM1: 192.168.181.175
>
> VM2: 192.168.181.174
>
> Host Machine - vmnet8 : 192.168.181.1

There is one http service running on VM2 at port 9990.

Now, the following works...

`VM2 -> Browser -> http://localhost:9990/some-path <- trying to access VM2's http service from VM2 itself, using "localhost"`

But, the below does not work.

`VM1 -> Browser -> http://192.168.181.174:9990/some-path <- trying to access VM2's http service from VM1`

`VM2 -> Browser -> http://192.168.181.174:9990/some-path <- trying to access VM2's http service from VM2 itself, using IP address`

Similarly, here is what telnet complains, from both VM1 and VM2

> telnet 192.168.181.174 9990
> Trying 192.168.181.174...
> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

And here is what the host machine's telnet complains,

> telnet 192.168.181.174 9990
> Trying 192.168.181.174...
> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host

The firewall is inactive on all - the host machine, VM1 and VM2.

Also, the ping from VM1 -> VM2, VM2 -> VM1, and Host-Machine -> VM1 or VM2 works fine.

I want VM1 to be able to access http service which is hosted on VM2. Can someone suggest how to get it through?

Note: I am primarily a software programmer/dev. I am not aware of nitty-gritty configurations of the firewalls etc. So in advance apologies, if the details provided are insufficient. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. :)

Look @ following.

`$ netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep 9990`

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9990          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Meaning, my web service on VM2 was not bound to 192.168.181.174, but to default - 127.0.0.1 (localhost). I have done appropriate changes in web server's configuration file. After restarting the web server, thins are working as per expectation. :)

Comment: Hi.. i also encountered this problem, how did you manage to solve it ? How did you bound the IP 192.168.181.174? Thanks